# Can Idris inline functions that are used as arguments?

Tags: templates, compiler-optimization, idris, inlining

In C++, if you were to write your own generic `sort` function template that takes a comparison predicate argument, then the compiler would be able to inline this predicate.

This is not the case in C: `qsort` is compiled once, and its comparison predicate argument is never inlined (Perhaps the compiler/linker state of the art improved lately, so please do correct me if my information is out-of-date)

This is a boon to generic programming in C++ (not just the `sort` function, of course): you can achieve the same performance, for which in C, you would have to abandon genericity (or use macros).

My question is: can Idris do what C++ does here? Can it inline functions that are used as arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idris does have support for partial evaluation of higher order function via an annotation mechanism. By marking the argument you expect to be passed at compile time `[static]`, you can get the resulting program to be specialised.

Cf. [the manual](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/partial-evaluation.html) for more details.